# the nbdev module loading issues

Tags: fast-ai

I just started working through the fast AI course. While trying to load this cell on google collab:

```
from nbdev.showdoc import *``
```

I encounter the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nbdev'. I've been trying to find an answer to this since a long time and couldnt find anything online. Any help in the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you pip installed nbdev?

Comment: Hey!, Thank you so much for responding. I changed fast ai version from 2 to 1 and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the Colab environment you need to add:

!pip install nbdev

from nbdev.showdoc import *

it will work.